# Iterating through array of objects, populating BarChart, and saving each as image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am creating an option in my application to create a PDF report based on the results from the application.

The results are represented as an ArrayCollection of XMLList objects, which I am using to populate a BarChart.

To create a screenshot of each result (as a PNG), I am loading the Results Window (a Title Window) and hiding it (visible = false).  I am using AlivePDF to add the capture to a PDF report.

I have been using a Timer to iterate through the results, load each result to the chart, create a delay, and then capture the image and add it to the report.

I am now questioning my strategy and I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion as to any other possibilities.

I thank you for your help in advance.

P.S. I am not creating a client/server application.  I need to create the images on the client side.

UPDATE

Sorry about the confusion with my question.

Currently, I am able to iterate through the results (using the Timer), but the chart does not refresh properly before capturing the screenshot and saving as PNG.

Essentially, I am trying to see if there is any other possible solutions for iterating through the results and creating a delay so that I may be able to load a result to the chart, capture the screenshot, and add it to a PDF.  Is there any other way to do this in Flex?

Initially, I was thinking of iterating through the results array using a for loop, but this was not working due to the fact that the results were not loading in time before capturing the screenshot of the chart.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part are you worried about and why?

Comment: Does it work properly ? I mean does it produce the result you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the chart's data it should *eventually* display the updated information. However the time taken will vary upon any number of factors so your best bet is to find out what event the chart dispatches once it updates. You may at that point want to capture the PNG as a callLater just in case you need an extra frame before the visual aspects are updated.

That said, this seems like a heavy-handed solution begging for an alternative.